# How to detect a keypress when console is not focused

Tags: c++, json, windows, event-handling

I have been designing a handler to make some connection between some external devices and my keyboard. For that I'm using C++ with `CkHttp` to send some http requests with `JSON`.

However my only problem seems to be detecting a system keypress while my console is not focused. I do not require the application to be portable C++ as I'm only developing it for windows.

As I tried to find some windows header function that could retrieve system keypress while unfocused but was unable to. Here is some of my process trying to use `SDL2` lib as a means to an end, unsuccessfully.

```
#undef main
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //init...

    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) //Doesnt work with unfocused window... Found no flags that could do it
        {
            //User requests quit
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
            //User presses a key
            else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                //Select surfaces based on key press
                switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_q:
                    hreq.putJSON(new HPacket(25500, 254, 254, 0));
                    hreq.putJSON(new HPacket(0, 254, 254, 3));
                    break;

                //some more handling...
                }
        //...
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Take in mind that using `SDL2` creates a `GUI`. I do not require that either, unless it works. A strict console would be fine, as long as it detects key presses in the background.

Comment: On Windows, the way that you can detect key-presses when the window isn't focused is by checking RawInput OR the easier way is to use SetWindowsHookEx and listen for the key press in that.

Comment: @Brandon `SetWindowsHookEx` worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Brandon my workaround involved the `SetWindowsHookEx()` windows function as a key handler.